# Absolute positioning appears under div

Tags: html, css

I have the following page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Absolute positioning</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        body {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr min-content;
            grid-template-areas: 
                "logo header" 
                "menu main" 
                "footer copyright";
            background: #f1f4fd;
            font-family: "Open Sans", "Segoe UI", Tahoma, sans-serif;
            font-size: 1em;
            color: #777d8b;
        }
        #logo {
            grid-area: logo;
            background: #7186c7;
            color: #fff;
        }
        #header {
            grid-area: header;
        }
        #menu {
            grid-area: menu;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            background: #7186c7;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 1em;
            min-width: 3em;
        }
        #main {
            grid-area: main;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
        #footer {
            grid-area: footer;
            background: #7186c7;
            color: #fff;
        }
        #copyright {
            grid-area: copyright;
            font-size: .9em;
        }
        .rel { position: relative; }
        .abs {
            position: absolute;
            left: 100px;
            top: 0;
            background: #c00;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }
        .bott { margin-top: 100px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="logo">Logo</header>
    <header id="header">Header</header>
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul class="abs">
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="rel bott">
            <li class="abs">test</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main id="main">Main</main>
    <footer id="footer">Footer</footer>
    <footer id="copyright">Copyright</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

There are two absolute positioned elements:

1. A whole ul inside the menu nav element
2. An li inside a ul inside the menu nav element

The first element is displayed normally, over the main region, but the li element is under the main region.

My questions:

1. Why is it happening (second - li element)?
2. How can I position it over the main region?

Update

Upon closer inspection, I found that it has something to do with overflow-y: scroll. If I remove it, everything works as expected.
But why does it happen?

Comment: A quick read in mdn about positioning will save you from downvotes

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean, can you point me to the page you mean?
I have read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position, but I still do not understand why it happens.

Comment: @AlexiosTsiaparas from what I understand is that you apply the `.abs` class which has the attribute of `position: absolute` the first time on your first `ul` but the second time you have it in your `li` element. Those elements are positioned based on their parent. So the second `ul` is positioned based on the element with the class `.rel bott` which has relative positioning. Also removing the `overflow-y` had no difference for me. Can you update your question to make it clear of what you want to achieve and probably we can give a hand and will help you understand the positioning. Thanks

Comment: Also I would suggest to start by applying different classes to each one instead of reusing them, once you have what you want then try to make them more generic and reusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow-y:hidden` is incompatible with `overflow-x:visible` (the default) so it's converted to `overflow-x:auto`.

The `position:relative` ul is thus contained within the menu scroll container, and provides the containing block for the `position:absolute` li. That li overflows the ul, which has zero height and width, but is still considered part of the rendering of the ul. so the overflow  is contained within the menu scroll container.

The `position:absolute` ul's containing block is the initial containing block and is positioned relative to that. It does not overflow anything and is not contained within the menu scroll container, so is painted on top of the main area.